# static object calls constructor at wrong time

Tags: c++, class, opengl, static, rendering

I have an opengl batch renderer, which has a static vao, vbo, ebo etc. problem is, int the constructor of those are opengl methods. now, because they are static the opengl methods like `glGenBuffers` get called before opengl has been initialized.

---

so you can get a better picture, this is how it looks:

```
class renderer2d
{
private:
    static vertex_array vao;
    static vertex_buffer vbo;
    static index_buffer ibo;

public:
    static void draw();
    static GLuint create_quad(glm::vec2 position, glm::vec2 size, GLfloat angle, glm::vec4 color);
}
```

and int the constructor of e.g. vao:

```
vao()
{
    //some sort of opengl method, that gets called without opengl being initialized
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &id);
}
```

---

btw, i dont only want to "solve" the problem while keeping the "static solution", if you have different ideas on how to do this, please tell me

Comment: Perhaps a use for the [nifty counter idiom](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Nifty_Counter).

Comment: Why not just make all members non-static and create an instance of `renderer2d` *after* `OpenGL` has been initialized and a valid context has been made current?  Or have I missed the point?

Comment: Well from what ive heard static methods are more efficient. And you wont need an instance in this case. So even if the efficiency doesnt really make a difference, i think its still good practice

Comment: @m100re but you *do* need multiple instance to draw multiple object.

Comment: Nope, im using batch rendering, i need exactly 1 instance of vao/vbo/ebo

Comment: well, then multiple batch.

Comment: No, in batch rendering you store the data of multiple shapes in 1 vbo. So i see no reason to creatr multiple instances if i only need 1

Comment: imho one generally should not force unnecessary constraint. for example, just like when singleton goes wrong. if you need one, then create one. in this case it means the class itself have no static member, but you can declare single (global) instance. (part of this comment is written before your reply)

Comment: Yes this could be an approach

Comment: One idea is to make a linked list through all the vao objects and then after initializing OpenGL, use the list to initialize all the objects automatically.

Comment: @m100re having a class with only static methods basically defeats the point of having a class to begin with. May as well just write the methods outside the class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One trick is to delay initialisation of the object like this:

```
renderer2d& get_renderer()
{
    static renderer2d renderer;
    return renderer;
}
```

This method works for any class, it does not require the renderer itself to have static data. The function can also be a static member of the class, as part of the Meyers singleton design.